# Allocating different sizes to an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to allocate an array different sizes in a loop. I am trying to do something like this.

```
  program generate

  implicit none

  real, allocatable :: stored_data(:)

  integer n, ii

  n = 256

  do ii = 1, 64

     allocate(stored_data(n*ii))

     ***** some operations ******

     deallocate(stored_data)

  end do

  stop
  end program generate
```

It is not working. Is this approach not possible? If not, what can I do?

Thank you

Comment: It worked when I compiled and ran it.  Why do you say it is not working?  Do you get an error message?  More info please...

Comment: It is compiling and running for me too. But where I mention ****some operations****, I am reading files of different length in each run. And I am only getting the right reading for the first loop. For all the other runs, I am getting garbage value. Ideally speaking, should this work? In that case I will look more carefully on other parts of the code...

Comment: Are you reading from the same file, or from different files?

Comment: I am sorry. I think I figured it out. There as no problem with the above allocation process. I had a bug somewhere else. Thank you.